# Assertion failed CV_Assert( CV_IS_MAT(objectPoints) && CV_IS_MAT(imagePoints) && CV_IS_MAT(A) && CV_IS_MAT(rvec) && CV_IS_MAT(tvec) )

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, aruco

I've calibrated a camera and obtained 0.17 reprojection error, the file is saved as `camera.yml`. Then, I imported this file to my aruco detection algorithm and when I run this algorithm, everything starts out fine until an aruco marker is detected, however, the moment an aruco marker is detected, the code throws the following error and stops running.

`cv exception: OpenCV(3.4.2) error: (-215:Assertion failed) (((objectPoints) != __null && (((const CvMat*)(objectPoints))->type & 0xFFFF0000) == 0x42420000 && ((const CvMat*)(objectPoints))->cols > 0 && ((const CvMat*)(objectPoints))->rows > 0) && ((const CvMat*)(objectPoints))->data.ptr != __null) && (((imagePoints) != __null && (((const CvMat*)(imagePoints))->type & 0xFFFF0000) == 0x42420000 && ((const CvMat*)(imagePoints))->cols > 0 && ((const CvMat*)(imagePoints))->rows > 0) && ((const CvMat*)(imagePoints))->data.ptr != __null) && (((A) != __null && (((const CvMat*)(A))->type & 0xFFFF0000) == 0x42420000 && ((const CvMat*)(A))->cols > 0 && ((const CvMat*)(A))->rows > 0) && ((const CvMat*)(A))->data.ptr != __null) && (((rvec) != __null && (((const CvMat*)(rvec))->type & 0xFFFF0000) == 0x42420000 && ((const CvMat*)(rvec))->cols > 0 && ((const CvMat*)(rvec))->rows > 0) && ((const CvMat*)(rvec))->data.ptr != __null) && (((tvec) != __null && (((const CvMat*)(tvec))->type & 0xFFFF0000) == 0x42420000 && ((const CvMat*)(tvec))->cols > 0 && ((const CvMat*)(tvec))->rows > 0) && ((const CvMat*)(tvec))->data.ptr != __null) in function 'cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2'`

The error is caused by

`CV_Assert( CV_IS_MAT(objectPoints) && CV_IS_MAT(imagePoints) && CV_IS_MAT(A) && CV_IS_MAT(rvec) && CV_IS_MAT(tvec) );`

that can be found in opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp, line #996 (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp).

I know that Rvecs and TVecs are generated with the help of calibration file. It looks like something in the calibration isn’t in the right format.

I have a sample calibration file (`sample.yml`) that belongs to another camera. When I import that file while running the aruco detection algorithm, it runs without any errors.

The contents of these files (in case you want to compare them) are available here:

- `camera.yml`: https://www.codepile.net/pile/mO4DGDOR
- `sample.yml`: https://www.codepile.net/pile/5qBKoNP6

I'm using OpenCV 3.4.2.

Comment: Can you also post the code you use?

Comment: @Kani it isn't an open source code, but (tomorrow) I can share a snippet of it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I am sorry, I was confused. Are you trying the calibration.cpp in the OpenCV repository?

Comment: @Kani yes, I used `calibration.cpp` to generate the camera calibration file: `camera.yml`

Comment: I am sorry, I am still confused. The first sentence in your question says you did the calibration and you obtained a re-projection error of 0.17. But then again you say "I imported this file to my aruco detection algorithm". Doesn't that mean that the `calibration.cpp` worked fine, but your detection code is not working?

Comment: @Kani I recorded a video for you: https://youtu.be/bBntRMxSobw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire problem is the discrepancy in the naming conventions between the two files. I copied the names from sample.yml to camera.yml and it started working. Sometimes the solution is that simple.

Comment: Glad that you figured that out. It's probably a version related issue between OpenCV and ArUco.

Comment: Wait, it's just that the names are lowercase in camera.yml and capitalized in sample.yml?  Grr.

Comment: I had a similiar issue with https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d4a/tutorial_charuco_detection.html  -- I worked around it by changing the `fs["camera_matrix"] >> camMatrix;` line to match the field name in the calibration file.  It would be cleaner if the `readCameraParameters()` routine was unable to read both calibration matrices from the config file would fault rather than pass a null.

Comment: I raised an issue here https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2949 and a bit of an error-check here https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/2950